# I get colon with my param using express for node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes

Here’s my routing :

```
router.route('/search:word').get(function(req, res) {
  var re = new RegExp(req.params.word, 'i');
  console.log(req.params.word);

  Place.find().or([{ 'title': { $regex: re }}, { 'category': { $regex: re }}]).sort('title').exec(function(err, places) {
    res.json(JSON.stringify(places));
  });
});
```

When I use the request `/places/search:test` the console displays :test instead of just "test".
Any idea what’s happening?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you really mean to use `router.route('/search:word')` instead of `router.route('/search/:word')`? Using colon there seems kind of odd.

If you use `router.route('/search/:word')`, and if your request is

`/places/search/test`

then you get `req.params.word="test"`

Comment: I see, but what if I really want to have an endpoint like `/search:word` Do I have to remove the colon myself when reading the parameter? Is that the way it's supposed to be? I'm learning Rest and Express... sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: If you want the end point as 'search:word' as literal string instead of parameter, you probably need to add another colon to escape it like mscdex said:  '/search::word'. I wouldn't use colon though.  It seems to break restful design pattern.  I would use slash ('/') between them instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you want same pattern api end point like eg:   `/places/search:test` then in api 
endpoint you have to use double colon. Example -

```
router.route('/search::word').get(function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params.word); ---> "test"
});
```

Thats why you are getting extra colon :test

Comment: My case is like /places/search/:word, it works great after adding another colon. But I have read a lot of articles about route parameters in Express, all of them mentioned that only one colon is used. Could you give any resources mentioning two colons? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

What's happening here is that it's breaking down the path to `/search[word]`. So when you request `/search:test`, [word] matches the part after `/search`, which would be `:test` in that case.

What you probably need instead is something like: `/search::word`